# Not receiving $_POST[] parameter

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to send a value from my test.php to my backgroundScript.php through the $_POST method and when print out the value that is being sent i get the correct value but when i go to my backgroundScript file to see if the value was sent - nothing gets printed out, it equals null --------------------------------test.php file - main code

```
try {  
  # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL  
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

  //$DBH->prepare('SELECT first FROM contacts');
}  
catch(PDOException $e) { 
    echo "I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that.";  
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);   
}  
//get query
$FNresult=$DBH->query('SELECT first FROM contacts'); 
//set fetch mode
$FNresult->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$dropdown = "<select name='contacts' id='contacts' >";

while($row =$FNresult->fetch()) {

  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option  value='{$row['first']}'>{$row['first']}</option>";
 // echo getLN();

}

$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

echo $dropdown;


//}
/*
//                  Get last name

function getLN(){
    $query = "SELECT last FROM contacts";
    $LNresult=mysql_query($query);

    $last;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($LNresult)) {

        $last = "{$row['last']}";

    }
    echo $last;
}//end getLN
*/

$DBH = null; 
?>


<script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>   
<!-- javascript on client-side -->
<script type="text/javascript">  

var dropdown = $('#contacts');

document.write(dropdown.val());

dropdown.bind('change', function(){

    $.post('backgroundScript.php', 
        { 
            first: dropdown.val()

        },
        function(response) {
            $('#first').val(response.first);
            $('#last').val(response.last);
            $('#phone').val(response.phone);
            // Repeat for all of your form fields
        },
        'json'
    );

});

</script>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" id="first"  ><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" id="last"><br>
Phone: <input type="text" id="phone"><br>
Mobile: <input type="text" id="mobile"><br>
Fax: <input type="text" id="fax"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" id="email"><br>
Web: <input type="text" id="web"><br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
```

backgroundScript.php ------------------------------------------- where value is sent

```
try {  
  # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL  
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

  //$DBH->prepare('SELECT first FROM contacts');
}  
catch(PDOException $e) { 
    echo "I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that.";  
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);   
}  

$first= $_POST['first'];
print_r("print value: $first");
//$first = "david";
$sth = $DBH->prepare('SELECT *
    FROM contacts
    WHERE first = :first');
$sth->bindParam(':first', $first, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();

$row = $sth->fetch();


$returnArray = array( 
'first' => $row["first"],
'last' => $row["last"], 
'phone' => $row["phone"], 
);
//print_r("After pureeing fruit, the colour is: $returnArray");
/*echo "<pre>";
print_r($returnArray);
echo "</pre>";
exit;*/


// background script

// retrieve data based on $_POST variable, set to $returnArray
/*while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  // do something with row

}
$returnArray = array( 
'first' => $row["first"], 
);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($returnArray);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
*/



/****************************
 * the structure of returnArray should look something like
     array(
         'first' => firstName,
         'last' => lastName,

     )*/
    // echo json_encode(array('first' => "hello", 'last' => "Other value"));
//echo json_encode($returnArray);
$DBH = null;
```

############################ UPDATE TO TEST.PHP

```
try {  
  # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL  
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

  //$DBH->prepare('SELECT first FROM contacts');
}  
catch(PDOException $e) { 
    echo "I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that.";  
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);   
}  
//get query
$FNresult=$DBH->query('SELECT first FROM contacts'); 
//set fetch mode
$FNresult->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


//}
/*
//                  Get last name

function getLN(){
    $query = "SELECT last FROM contacts";
    $LNresult=mysql_query($query);

    $last;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($LNresult)) {

        $last = "{$row['last']}";

    }
    echo $last;
}//end getLN
*/

$DBH = null; 
?>


<script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>   
<!-- javascript on client-side -->
<script type="text/javascript">  

var dropdown = $('#contacts');

document.write(dropdown.val());

dropdown.bind('change', function(){

    $.post('backgroundScript.php', 
        { 
            first: dropdown.val()

        },
        function(response) {
            $('#first').val(response.first);
            $('#last').val(response.last);
            $('#phone').val(response.phone);
            // Repeat for all of your form fields
        },
        'json'
    );

});

</script>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<?php

$dropdown = "<select name='contacts' id='contacts' >";

while($row =$FNresult->fetch()) {

  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option  value='{$row['first']}'>{$row['first']}</option>";
 // echo getLN();

}

$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";



echo $dropdown;
?>

First Name: <input type="text" name="first" id="first" ><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" id="last"><br>
Phone: <input type="text" id="phone"><br>
Mobile: <input type="text" id="mobile"><br>
Fax: <input type="text" id="fax"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" id="email"><br>
Web: <input type="text" id="web"><br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
```

Now i get a undefined  in javascript when i try to print out value of dropdown

######################################## UPDATE

```
<form action="backgroundScript.php" method="post">

<script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>   
<!-- javascript on client-side -->
<script type="text/javascript">  

var dropdown = $('#contacts');

document.write(dropdown.val());

dropdown.bind('change', function(){

    $.post('backgroundScript.php', 
        { 
            first: dropdown.val()

        },
        function(response) {
            $('#first').val(response.first);
            $('#last').val(response.last);
            $('#phone').val(response.phone);
            // Repeat for all of your form fields
        },
        'json'
    );

});

</script>


<?php

$dropdown = "<select name='contacts' id='contacts' >";

while($row =$FNresult->fetch()) {

  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option  value='{$row['first']}'>{$row['first']}</option>";
}
$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

echo $dropdown;
?>

First Name: <input type="text" name="first" id="first" ><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last" id="last"><br>
Phone: <input type="text"  name="phone" id="phone"><br>
Mobile: <input type="text" id="mobile"><br>
Fax: <input type="text" id="fax"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" id="email"><br>
Web: <input type="text" id="web"><br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POST uses `name` instead of `id` to identify parameters. Use `name` on your fields - or use both.

```
<input type="text" name="first" id="first" >
```

Javascript can make do of IDs nicely with the whole `getElementByID` but POST and GET data needs the `name` to be used.

Edit: You also need to make sure that the `<select....>` statement falls inside the `<form>` and `</form>` tags, otherwise it isn't sent as part of that form.

Stick this line:

```
<form action="backgroundScript.php" method="post">
```

above these lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>   
<!-- javascript on client-side -->
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Edit 2: Also, as Herpa points out, your `<form action=''>` is set to `insert.php` and not `backgroundScript.php`. You need to change that as well.

Comment: but at the top in php code im sending the value of the what ever dropdown option was selected - but it does not go all the way through to the $first = $_POST['first']

Comment: Because you have to send "name" and not "id"

Comment: @DavidBiga I made an edit to the post, but what guy above? I was the first answer.

Comment: Okay i did and I still get it as undefined

Comment: I figured it out - now its defined...now im stil trying to get a value sent to $first= $_POST['first']; in backgroundScript and print it out but i got nothing still

Answer (score 1):

Change this in the test.php file:

```
<form action="backgroundScript.php.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" id="first" ><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" id="last"><br>
Phone: <input type="text" id="phone"><br>
Mobile: <input type="text" id="mobile"><br>
Fax: <input type="text" id="fax"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" id="email"><br>
Web: <input type="text" id="web"><br>
<?php echo $dropdown; ?>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
```

The action attribute of the form tag shows where to send the POST data. In your script you were sending it to insert.php. You should also user the name attribute to get the name of the input field through the POST variable.
Edit: You were echoing the select outside the form.

Comment: wait up i am trying to send the parameter from the php code above on top of test.php where this is made ------ dropdown = "<select name='contacts' id='contacts' >";

while($row =$FNresult->fetch()) {

  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option  value='{$row['first']}'>{$row['first']}</option>";
 // echo getLN();

}

$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

echo $dropdown; --------- then first takes it and send it into the backgroundScript.php file

Comment: You are currently sending the parameter to insert.php not to backgroundScript.php. As I said the action attribute shows where to send the $_POST variable, so in order to send it you have to make action="backgroundScript.php". Also when you echo the $dropdown you don't echo it in the form you echo it outside the form.

Comment: the insert was only to be used to add to db the javascript handled calling the background script. So i am kinda confused.

Comment: Check the edit i made in the answer. Also you can do the insert in the  backgroundScript. After you send the POST variables to the insert.php you won't be able to sent them to the backgroundScript.php . In order to do that you'll have to write the whole $_POST array to a $_SESSION variable and then use the $_SESSION variable in the backgroundScript.php